# Solution to a second order non-linear ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need help solving two (unrelated) non-linear second order ODE's. Let me just preface this by saying that I don't know much/anything about ODE's (I'm only 17).

Well, so here's the first equation:

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\frac{x^2\gamma}{A}+2x\mu \left(\frac{dx}{dt}+\alpha\right)+A\eta \left(\frac{dx}{dt}+\alpha\right)^2=0$$

And here's the second equation:

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\left(\frac{dx}{dt}+u\right)^2\left(\frac{A}{r_0-\omega_0t}\right)^2=0$$

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Also- if for some reason these equations don't have a solution in terms of standard mathematical functions (or their solutions are extremely complicated), it would be good enough to have, for each equation, a relation $x=f(A)$ (although I'm not sure how that could be done). Another option would be to try a numerical solution, but that I really don't know anything about.

Ps. This isn't for homework on ODE's or anything. I was just solving a physics problem and arrived at those equations (for two independent parts of the problem), and need a solution soon because this is for a school lab.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange! This is a nice set of problems. Usually it's better to post questions one at a time. Now to your questions: In general, it is very difficult to impossible to come up with closed form solutions of ordinary differential equations. This is possibly the case for the first equation (but there is hope). As to the second problem, see my answer below.

Comment: Thanks! I'm very new to stackexchange, so I wasn't aware of this; I'll keep it in mind for the future. 
Thanks also for your solution of the second equation. I'll see if I can simplify some parts of the physical situation to adjust the first equation, in the case that it can't be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second problem can be handled by reducing the order: Set $y(t) = \frac{dx}{dt} + u$. Then 
$$
\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\left(\frac{dx}{dt}+u\right)^2\left(\frac{A}{r_0-\omega_0t}\right)^2=0
$$
becomes
$$
\frac{dy}{dt}+y(t)^2\left(\frac{A}{r_0-\omega_0t}\right)^2=0
$$
Now use separation of variables: The equation becomes
$$
\frac{1}{y(t)^2}\frac{dy}{dt} + \left(\frac{A}{r_0-\omega_0t}\right)^2=0
$$
which after integration turns into
$$
\frac{-1}{y(t)} + \frac{A^2}{\omega_0(r_0 - \omega_0t)} = C_0
$$
where $C_0$ is a constant of integration. Solve this:
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} + u = y(t) = \frac{1}{\frac{A^2}{\omega_0(r_0 - \omega_0t)} - C_0}
$$
You now know $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and thus you can find $x(t)$. There will be another constant of integration.

Comment: Thanks very much! That's incredibly helpful.